# How do I create a 2d array in my class that stores names and prices as strings in C#?

Tags: c#, class, multidimensional-array

How do I create a 2d array in my class that stores names and prices as strings? And how do I make it accessible from my form without using an object? So far I have the following in my class.

```
class Name
{
    public string SpecialCakeName()
    {
        string[,] strSpecialCakeName = new string[4, 2];

        strSpecialCakeName[0, 0] = " ";
        strSpecialCakeName[0, 1] = " ";
        strSpecialCakeName[1, 0] = " ";
        strSpecialCakeName[1, 1] = " ";
        strSpecialCakeName[2, 0] = " ";
        strSpecialCakeName[2, 1] = " ";
        strSpecialCakeName[3, 0] = " ";
        strSpecialCakeName[3, 1] = " ";

        return strSpecialCakeName[0,0];
    }
}
```

However, I don't know that this is even the right approach. Also how would I be able to access this array without using something like 'Name cakeName = new Name();' in my form?

Comment: Don't store price information as a string. Just don't. Instead, use the **decimal** type for anything to do with money, and only convert to a string at the last possible moment before displaying to the user.

Comment: You MUST using an array or can you using lists or dictionnaries ?

Comment: @MarcDeletang, yes for this I must use an array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest a **[Dictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx)** object. Using strings to store price information is a bad idea. A Dictionary<string,decimal> will allow you map a string cake name to a decimal price without needing to define a whole custom object (though, really, that may be what you need here).

To access the dictionary without needing an instance of your class, build it like this:

```
public class Names
{
    private static Dictionary<string, decimal> _specialCakes = new Dictionary<string,decimal>{
                {"Cake 1", 1.00m},
                {"Cake 2", 2.50m},
                {"Cake 3", 4.00m}
          };

    public static Dictionary<string, decimal> SpecialCakes {
           get {return _specialCakes;}
    }
}
```

Now you can look up a price like this:

```
decimal Cake1Price = Names.SpecialCakes["Cake 1"];
```

Or loop through a list of all cake names like this:

```
foreach(string name in Names.SpecialCakes.Keys)
{
    //and within the loop reference a price for that cake like this:
    decimal currentPrice = Names.SpecialCakes[name];
}
```

Comment: Your dictionary definition didn't compile, I updated it appropriately

Comment: @Kiviuq Then this is how you should do it.  Since the assignment is done you don't really need to worry about the academic constraints that you won't have in the job market.

Comment: @Kiviuq This is a _contrived_ example. They ask you to do it this way to help you and become comfortable with the syntax for multi-dimensional and jagged arrays. However, matching price information is really not a very good example, and your professor would do better to come up with an example of matching two different strings... one idea is first name/last name pairs.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn, thank you for that. Yes I've noticed my prof has used recycled material and given us supplimentary notes that look to be from a slide show presentation and they do not always make sense from an online perspective. I've emailed him about a dozen times and have yet to get a response for him. It is rather frustrating, but that you for your help.  Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Make it static:

```
public static string SpecialCakeName()
{
...
}
```

then you can call it using class type:

```
string[,] names = Name.SpecialCakeName();
```

Comment: when I put in your class type I got an error saying "An object reference is required for the non-static field, method or property 'System.Windows.Form.Control.Name.get'

Comment: ah, Name is Framework System.Windows.Form.Control property. Specify full namespace in front of your Name class when you call Name.SpecialCakeName() or better - change your Name class name to something more descriptive.

Answer (score 0):

Use Dictionary instead.

```
Dictionary<string, decimal> strSpecialCakeName = new Dictionary<string, decimal>();
strSpecialCakeName.Add({"somename", 100/*some decimal price*/});
```